# CORS issue between PHP API and Vue 3 (Vite) app

Tags: php, vue.js, cors, vite

I'm building an app with Vue 3 + Vite. My API is developed with PHP. On my local, I'm using Vite's `proxy` and that work's just fine along with my `.env.local` variable of `VITE_API_URL=/api/`. Vite handles that and pushes it towards the proxy URL during dev.

Once I go to production, my app uses the `.env.production` variable of `VITE_API_URL=https://api.myapp.com`, naturally since Vite ignores the `proxy` during `npm build`.

My PHP API already has the required CORS headers set (or so I think, since I've been through a ton of threads here). My app is running from beta.myapp.com towards api.myapp.com -- the subdomains differ. The app is `beta` and the API is `api`. So these are my PHP headers.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://beta.myapp.com");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') exit(0);
```

And still my Vue app in production keeps on getting this issue:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.myapp.com/api/getOptions' from origin 'https://beta.myapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have even tried changing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` (not recommended), but I tried it and even that doesn't work.